# I want to install Windows Server 2008 on my laptop

Tags: windows, flash, windows-server

I want to install Windows Server 2008 on my laptop, but I wondering if I can install programs like Adobe flash and 3D Max and other gaming programs and it will works perfectly on windows Server or I will face any problems.

Answer (score 4):

All programs should work equally on both workstation and server editions of Windows. The only major difference is that by default, Server editions are configured to give priority to background services, which is not optimal for desktop/laptop use; however, it is easy to reconfigure the system (under *System Properties*) to give more resources to foreground programs.